# How to define property type in SampledProperty in Cesium

Tags: javascript, polygon, cesiumjs

I am using Cesiumjs to create a polygon which is moving around an area.

To show its movement I tried to create a `sampledProperty`of `PolygonHierarchy`. Each sample is an array of `Cartesian3` positions (three endpoints of my polygon at each time step).

I need to know the type of the `property` that I am using in `sampledProperty` as it is mentioned in Cesiumjs website: [Cesiumjs.org/SampledProperty](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/SampledProperty.html?classFilter=sampled).

But I don't know how to define it and I couldn't find any explanation on the website on how to identify property type especially when each sample by itself is an array of properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SampledProperty` doesn't work here, since it attempts to interpolate smoothly between the points you've given it, and it doesn't know how to interpolate a polygon hierarchy.

So instead, you can use a [`TimeIntervalCollectionProperty`](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/TimeIntervalCollectionProperty.html).  The difference here is that this property animates by steps, not interpolation, so the property does not need to know how to construct the intermediate values between control points.

I made a small demo, to show how this works with a polygon hierarchy.  Click `Run Code Snippet` at the bottom, or copy-and-paste just the JavaScript into [Sandcastle](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html).

```js
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {
    navigationInstructionsInitiallyVisible: false
});

// Set up a limited range of time for this demo.
var time = Cesium.JulianDate.fromIso8601('2016-04-08T12:00:00Z');
viewer.clock.clockRange = Cesium.ClockRange.LOOP_STOP;
viewer.clock.startTime = time;
viewer.clock.currentTime = time;
viewer.clock.stopTime = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(time, 20, new Cesium.JulianDate());
viewer.clock.multiplier = 1;
viewer.timeline.updateFromClock();
viewer.timeline.zoomTo(time, viewer.clock.stopTime);

// Construct a TimeIntervalCollection showing the changes to the hierarchy over time.
var hierarchy = new Cesium.TimeIntervalCollectionProperty();

for (var i = 0; i < 40; ++i) {
    var nextTime = Cesium.JulianDate.addSeconds(time, 0.5, new Cesium.JulianDate());

    // Inside the loop, per iteration we add one window of time for this polygon.
    hierarchy.intervals.addInterval(new Cesium.TimeInterval({
        start: time,
        stop: nextTime,
        isStartIncluded : true,
        isStopIncluded : false,
        data : Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights([-108.0+i/4, 35.0, 100000,
                                                          -100.0+i/4, 35.0, 100000,
                                                          -100.0+i/4, 40.0, 100000,
                                                          -108.0+i/4, 40.0, 100000])
    }));
    
    time = nextTime;
}

// Create the polygon, using the animated hierarchy.
var orangePolygon = viewer.entities.add({
    name : 'Orange polygon with time-varying position',
    polygon : {
        hierarchy : hierarchy,
        extrudedHeight: 0,
        perPositionHeight : true,
        material : Cesium.Color.ORANGE.withAlpha(0.5),
        outline : true,
        outlineColor : Cesium.Color.WHITE
    }
});

viewer.zoomTo(viewer.entities);
```

```css
html, body, #cesiumContainer {
  width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.19/Build/Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css" 
      rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://cesiumjs.org/releases/1.19/Build/Cesium/Cesium.js">
</script>
<div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Based on your answer, I cannot see a polygon smoothly moving over a region, unless I make my time steps too small I guess.

Comment: I have two comments: 1. Is there any method (or maybe a list) which returns the type of a property, if it could interpolate. 2. I saw an example for moving polygon, using references to the position of its endpoints in **CZML** which moves smoothly, I couldn't make it work in _javascript_ though. Is it just available in **CZML**?

Comment: 1. For SampledProperty, it is [`SampledProperty.type`](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/SampledProperty.html#type).  There is no corresponding type of a TimeIntervalCollection, since each interval could potentially represent a different data type.  2. Can you post the CZML, or link to CZML?  Generally anything you can do in CZML you can do via Entity API.

Comment: 1. Thank you, I didn't know that, I thought I have to be specific about the type of the object. 2.  You can find the czml in [onedrive link](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DD9949F85826568D!498&authkey=!AM_-vnfpeyx82TY&ithint=file%2cczml), it is based on the answer in the google group [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/SK8wN7t2MGs). I can ask this question separately as 
"how to reference positions of other entities in polygon hierarchy of Cesium using javascript", if you think it is more helpful!

Comment: Sure, that sounds like a separate question.  Thanks!

Comment: I did, you can find the link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36586570/how-to-reference-positions-of-other-entities-in-polygon-hierarchy-of-cesium-usin)

Comment: Hi @emackey how to animate coordinate with hierarchy ? i have raised a question https://stackoverflow.com/q/68032225/4720950 can you advise .. thank you