# How to reference positions of other entities in polygon hierarchy of Cesium using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reference, polygon, cesiumjs

I am using Cesium to visualize my scenario and I want to create a polygon in *JavaScript* using position of other moving entities as references for its endpoints. As suggested in the answer of [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cesium-dev/SK8wN7t2MGs) by using *CZML*.

I was wondering if I can do it (referencing positions of other entities as endpoints of my polygon) in *JavaScript*. I tried a few things and it didn't work, for example, following is my code:

```
var newPoly= viewer.entities.add({                                            
    id : resourceSet[objIndex].id+"poly",
    name:resourceSet[objIndex].id+"poly",
    availability : new Cesium.TimeIntervalCollection([new Cesium.TimeInterval({
        start : start,
        stop : stop
    })]),
    polygon:{
        hierarchy :{
            positions:{
                references:[
                     Cesium.ReferenceProperty.fromString(collection, ''+entityName+'#position'),
                     Cesium.ReferenceProperty.fromString(collection, ''+baseEntity[0].id+'#position'),
                     Cesium.ReferenceProperty.fromString(collection, ''+baseEntity[1].id+'#position')
                ]
            }
        },
        material :Cesium.Color.AQUA.withAlpha(0.5),
        perPositionHeight : true,
        show : true
    },
    show: true
})
```

For references I also tried :

- just using entity and positions like: `entity.position`
- Using `entity$position`.

None of them worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entity properties have a function getValue that takes a JulianDate time as a parameter and returns the value at that time.
To get a position, you should be able to do something like

```
var position = entity.position.getValue(viewer.clock.currentTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me in JavaScript was to define the `positions` property with `new Cesium.PositionPropertyArray([])`.

[This post on Cesium's Community Forum](https://community.cesium.com/t/cannot-make-polyline-dynamically-attach-and-move-between-two-point-entities/8094/2) by Scott_Hunter helped me, specifically the second link to Sandcastle.